# Retrieve and use query params inside a QGIS server project file

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, ogc-api-features

I have a QGIS project hosted using the [camptocamp/qgis-server docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/camptocamp/qgis-server).

Everything goes fine. But I would like to retrieve (and use inside the QGIS project itself) some of the query parameters send by the user browsing the layer in its web browser:
e.g. using an OGC API Features endpoint:

GET https://base-url.org/wfs3/collections/mycollection/items?id=1&username=johndoe

for which the server says (inside the docker container):

```
qgisserver_1  | 1009 - 172.xx.xx.xx - - [30/Apr/2022:12:28:46 +0000] "GET /wfs3/static/jsonFormatter/jsonFormatter.min.js HTTP/1.0" 200 1480 "https://base-url.org/wfs3/collections/mycollection/items?id=1&username=johndoe" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0"
```

let's say I'd like to retrieve the `username` `johndoe` inside my QGIS project, and do stuff with it, or storing it in a database to keep track of who is browsing the app at what time for example.

This is a dummy example to explain the idea. In fact I'd like to retrieve the whole set of query params to store in database, for example the user that has pushed some modifications when transactions are enabled on that endpoint:

[image: transactions enables on WFS3 in QGIS server]

Comment: Did you try to contact the cartocamp?

Comment: OGC API Features standard does not yet handle transactions (akin to WFS-T), but it is in draft http://docs.ogc.org/DRAFTS/20-002.html